# How to use JWT based local storage login for react Facebook and Google Login options?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, local-storage, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-signin

My web app based on **REACT JS** client side with **PHP** APIs on server side.

I m already using **JWT** token based **SIGN UP** for users where a token is saved in **local Storage** if user logs in and is authenticated.

See this Login API I call for **Login**:

```js
const credentials = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }

    axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/login.php', credentials, {
    headers: {
        'Accept' : 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }})
  .then(response => {
            const  token = response.data.jwt;
            localStorage.setItem("jwttoken", token);
            alert("You are Logged In as Valued Customer");
            this.setState({redirectToReferrer: true});
                   })
      .catch(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Soryy Cannot Login to Customer Account!!!");}
        });
```

Now I m using **Facebook** and **Google** Signup Options like this on Signup.js Page:

```js
signupS(res, type) {
     let postData;
     if (type === 'facebook' && res.email) {
     postData = {
          FirstName: res.name,
          provider: type,
          email: res.email,
          provider_id: res.id,
          token: res.accessToken,
          provider_pic: res.picture.data.url
     };
    }

    if (type === 'google' && res.w3.U3) {
    postData = {
      FirstName: res.w3.ig,
      provider: type,
      email: res.w3.U3,
      provider_id: res.El,
      token: res.Zi.access_token,
      provider_pic: res.w3.Paa
    };
}

if (postData) {
  console.log(postData);
  axios.post('http://localhost/Auth/api/customers/create_customer.php', postData)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.data);
    alert("Congratulations! Your Customer Account is created");
    this.setState({redirectToReferrer: true});
    return result;
   })
} else {}
}



render () {

      if (this.state.redirectToReferrer) {
        return (<Redirect to={'/loginc'}/>)
      }
      const responseFacebook = (response) => {
        console.log("facebook console");
        console.log(response);
        this.signupS(response, 'facebook');
    }

    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        console.log("google console");
        console.log(response);
        this.signupS(response, 'google');
    }

return (

<div>
    <FacebookLogin
          appId="my-api" 
          fields="name,email,picture"
          callback={responseFacebook}
        />
   
        <GoogleLogin
          clientId="my-g-api" 
          buttonText="LOGIN WITH GOOGLE"
          onSuccess={responseGoogle}
          onFailure={responseGoogle}
        />
 
    </div>
    ))}
```

Now When I run this, Im taking only **email and name** from facebook/Google and sending it to my same API for **create_account** which I was already using. And becoz Im sending **No Password** So account is not being created.

Now What Im confused at, is that ***"Do I have to send this provider_id and token along the facebook & Google credentials?*** Or Can I just ***send a password(same which user used for Facebook) along this all***?

I want to keep the login way with the JWT token, so what do I do with this token of **Facebook/Google?**

Comment: _“Or Can I just send a password(same which user used for Facebook) along this all?”_ - if you knew the user’s actual Facebook password, you’d be doing things completely wrong already. _“so what do I do with this token of Facebook/Google?”_ - check that the authentication is genuine, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to send anything to your backend other than the **access token** for Google/Facebook. At your server side, you can use the google API (by providing the client id and secret) to check for the integrity of the access token. If the token is valid, it would in turn return you the profile for which the access token was generated. You can use the profile details to create your customer.
Hope this helped!